# Как сделать функцию округления в tkinter калькулятор

Tags: python, tkinter

Я делаю калькулятор, и хочю сделать функцию округления и привязать к кнопке ≈, я не понимаю как это сделать.

Если что, я делаю чисто для себя украинский калькулятор.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import time

root = Tk()
root.title("Калькулятор")
#root.geometry("200x500")
# root.config(bg = "black")

#Логіка калькулятора
def calc(key):
    global memory
    if key == "=":
        
#виключаєм написання букв
        strl = "-+0123456789.*/()"
        if calc_entry.get()[0] not in strl:
            #calc_entry.delete(0, END)
            messagebox.showerror("Помилка!", "Ви ввели не число!")
#рахунок
        try:
            result = eval(calc_entry.get())
            calc_entry.delete(0, END)
            sum = calc_entry.insert(END, str(result))
            
        except:
            #calc_entry.delete(0, END)
            messagebox.showerror("Помилка", "Перевір правильність данних")
            #calc_label.config(text = "Перевір правильність данних")

#очистити поле

    elif key == "C":
        calc_entry.delete(0, END)
    
    elif key == "⌫":
        txt = calc_entry.get()[:-1]

        calc_entry.delete(0, END)
        
        calc_entry.insert(0, txt)

    elif key == "≈":
        #и тут я незнаю что делать, нужно чтобы sum округлилось

    else:
        if "=" in calc_entry.get():
            calc_entry.delete(0, END)
        calc_entry.insert(END, key)

# Всі кнопки
bttn_list = [
    "7", "8", "9", "⌫", "C",
    "4", "5", "6", "*", "/",
    "1", "2", "3", "+", "-",
    "0", ".", "(", ")", "=",
    "≈"
]

r = 1
c = 0

for i in bttn_list:
    rel = ""
    cmd = lambda x=i: calc(x)
    ttk.Button(root, text=i, command=cmd).grid(row=r, column=c)
    c += 1
    if c>4:
        c=0
        r += 1

# calc_label = Label(root, bg = "red", width=63)
# calc_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

calc_entry = Entry(root, width=63)
calc_entry.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Что-то вроде `entry.set(str(int(float(entry.get())))` ?

Comment: Пофиг как, главное чтобы Entry sum округлялся. Но лучше способом round

Comment: `round(a, b)` a это число float, b это кол-во знаков после точки.